# Loop pages and save contents in Excel file from website in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to loop pages from this [link](http://so.eastmoney.com/Ann/s?keyword=%E8%B4%AD%E4%B9%B0%E7%89%A9%E4%B8%9A&pageindex=2) and extract the interesting part.

Please see the contents in the red circle in the image below.

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
url = 'http://so.eastmoney.com/Ann/s?keyword=购买物业&pageindex={}'
for page in range(10):
    r = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
```

xpath for each element (might be helpful for those that don't read Chinese):

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/h3/span  --> 【润华物业】
/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/h3/a --> 润华物业:关于公司购买理财产品的公告
/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/p/label --> 2017-04-24
/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/p/span --> 公告编号：2017-019 证券代码：836007 证券简称：润华物业  主办券商：国联证券
/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/a --> http://data.eastmoney.com/notices/detail/836007/AN201704250530124271,JWU2JWI2JWE2JWU1JThkJThlJWU3JTg5JWE5JWU0JWI4JTlh.html
```

I need to save the output to an Excel file. How could I do that in Python? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` won't see this stuff, as it's rendered dynamically by `JS`, but there's an API endpoint you can query to get what you're after.

Here's how:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


def clean_up(text: str) -> str:
    return text.replace('</em>', '').replace(':<em>', '').replace('<em>', '')


def get_data(page_number: int) -> dict:
    url = f"http://searchapi.eastmoney.com/business/Web/GetSearchList?type=401&pageindex={page_number}&pagesize=10&keyword=购买物业&name=normal"
    headers = {
        "Referer": f"http://so.eastmoney.com/Ann/s?keyword=%E8%B4%AD%E4%B9%B0%E7%89%A9%E4%B8%9A&pageindex={page_number}",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0",
    }
    return requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()


def parse_response(response: dict) -> list:
    for item in response["Data"]:
        title = clean_up(item['NoticeTitle'])
        date = item['NoticeDate']
        url = item['Url']
        notice_content = clean_up(" ".join(item['NoticeContent'].split()))
        company_name = item['SecurityFullName']
        print(f"{company_name} - {title} - {date}")
        yield [title, url, date, company_name, notice_content]


def save_results(parsed_response: list):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        parsed_response,
        columns=['title', 'url', 'date', 'company_name', 'content'],
    )
    df.to_excel("test_output.xlsx", index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    output = []
    for page in range(1, 11):
        for parsed_row in parse_response(get_data(page)):
            output.append(parsed_row)

    save_results(output)
```

This outputs:

```
栖霞物业购买资产的公告 - 2019-09-03 16:00:00 - 871792
索克物业购买资产的公告 - 2020-08-17 00:00:00 - 832816
中都物业购买股权的公告 - 2019-12-09 16:00:00 - 872955
开元物业:开元物业购买银行理财产品的公告 - 2015-05-21 16:00:00 - 831971
开元物业:开元物业购买银行理财产品的公告 - 2015-04-12 16:00:00 - 831971
盛全物业:拟购买房产的公告 - 2017-10-30 16:00:00 - 834070
润华物业购买资产暨关联交易公告 - 2016-08-23 16:00:00 - 836007
润华物业购买资产暨关联交易公告 - 2017-08-14 16:00:00 - 836007
萃华珠宝:关于拟购买物业并签署购买意向协议的公告 - 2017-07-10 16:00:00 - 002731
赛意信息:关于购买办公物业的公告 - 2020-12-02 00:00:00 - 300687
```

And saves this to a `.csv` file that can be easily handled by excel.

[image]

PS. I don't know Chinese (?) so you'd have to look into the response contents and pick more stuff out.

Comment: I was looking for that but couldn't find it. Where did you find the api url?

Comment: @chitown88 it's in the Developer Tool -> Network -> Other and it's the one with `GetSearchList` initiated by jquery. If you drop the jquery param from the url, you'll get a pure JSON response.

Comment: ah ok. I see. I didn't check under `Other`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also updated xpath for each elements if it's relevant.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can set up a `for loop` to "paginate" through the pages, if you wish.

Comment: Great code, many thanks, I also tried loop pages, but it doesn't works, because I have't pass `page` to `url` and `headers`, please check the solution below.

Comment: Could you please rewrite and add `save_results` function by saving result with pandas's dataframe? BTW, what `->` represents in your code?

Comment: @ahbon I've updated the answer. This `-> str` indicates type of the return value.

Comment: Based on this question, I ask a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65176880/loop-url-from-dataframe-and-download-pdf-files-in-python, if you have time, please check, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer based on @baduker's solution, but not working out for loop pages.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

for page in range(10):
    url = "http://searchapi.eastmoney.com/business/Web/GetSearchList?type=401&pageindex={}&pagesize=10&keyword=购买物业&name=normal"
    headers = {
        "Referer": "http://so.eastmoney.com/Ann/s?keyword=%E8%B4%AD%E4%B9%B0%E7%89%A9%E4%B8%9A&pageindex={}",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0",
    }
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    
    output_data = []
    for item in response["Data"]:
        # print(item)
        # print('*' * 40)
        title = item['NoticeTitle'].replace('</em>', '').replace(':<em>', '').replace('<em>', '')
        url = item['Url']
        date = item['NoticeDate'].split(' ')[0]
        company_name = item['SecurityFullName']
        content = item['NoticeContent'].replace('</em>', '').replace(':<em>', '').replace('<em>', '')
        # url_code = item['Url'].split('/')[5]
        output_data.append([title, url, date, company_name, content])

names = ['title', 'url', 'date', 'company_name', 'content']
df = pd.DataFrame(output_data, columns = names)
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index = False)
```