# Loop url from dataframe and download pdf files in Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

Based on the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65106061/loop-pages-and-save-contents-in-excel-file-from-website-in-python), I'm able to crawler `url` for each transation and save them into [an excel file which can be downloaded here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/mu3eevcdl9rnd4hesxt4b/test_output.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=46q80vddukkbyu0o0jiy0u398).

Now I would like to go further and click the `url` link:

[image]

For each `url`, I will need to open and save `pdf` format files:

[image]

How could I do that in Python? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for references:

```
import shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = 'xxx'
for page in range(6):
    r = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.select("h3[class='sv-card-title']>a"):
        r = requests.get(link.get("href"), stream=True)
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        with open('./files/' + link.text + '.pdf', 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Comment: The `link.text` probably is `"查看PDF原文"`.Do you really want to rename the file as it?Otherwise the pdf file you have downloaded would be covered.

Comment: It would be ideal if named by title of each transaction, or the last part of url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of download a pdf file in your uploaded excel file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Let's assume there is only one page.If you need to download many files, save them in a list.

url = 'http://xinsanban.eastmoney.com/Article/NoticeContent?id=AN201909041348533085'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

link = soup.select_one(".lookmore")
title = soup.select_one(".newsContent").select_one("h1").text

print(title.strip() + '.pdf')
data = requests.get(link.get("href")).content
with open(title.strip().replace(":", "-") + '.pdf', "wb+") as f: # file name shouldn't contain ':', so I replace it to "-"
    f.write(data)
```

And download successfully:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's bit different approach. You don't have to open those urls from the excel file as you can build the `.pdf` file source urls yourself.

For example:

```
import requests

urls = [
    "http://data.eastmoney.com/notices/detail/871792/AN201909041348533085,JWU2JWEwJTk2JWU5JTljJTllJWU3JTg5JWE5JWU0JWI4JTlh.html",
    "http://data.eastmoney.com/notices/detail/872955/AN201912101371726768,JWU0JWI4JWFkJWU5JTgzJWJkJWU3JTg5JWE5JWU0JWI4JTlh.html",
    "http://data.eastmoney.com/notices/detail/832816/AN202008171399155565,JWU3JWI0JWEyJWU1JTg1JThiJWU3JTg5JWE5JWU0JWI4JTlh.html",
    "http://data.eastmoney.com/notices/detail/831971/AN201505220009713696,JWU1JWJjJTgwJWU1JTg1JTgzJWU3JTg5JWE5JWU0JWI4JTlh.html",
]

for url in urls:
    file_id, _ = url.split('/')[-1].split(',')
    pdf_file_url = f"http://pdf.dfcfw.com/pdf/H2_{file_id}_1.pdf"
    print(f"Fetching {pdf_file_url}...")
    with open(f"{file_id}.pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(pdf_file_url).content)
```

Comment: Thanks, would you mind to add your code to your answer in last question. It could be very helpful.