# Loop url from excel file, download pdf files and name them with combination of multiple columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

Given a test data from [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6md9m10f6md5y1iwvyoo4/test1.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=bl7yts55wz0y4t4t1g43rpzar):

[image]

I would like to read excel file and loop all the `url`s, then download pdf files, and named them with combination of `city-type-year-quarter.pdf`, ie. for the first file, it would be `guangzhou-retail-2021-q2.pdf`.

How could I do that based on the code below? Thanks.

**Updated code:**

```
df = pd.read_excel('test1.xlsx')
urls = df['url'].tolist()
# df.columns
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    with open(f"{}_{}_{}_{}.pdf".format(row.city, row.type, row.year, row.quarter), "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(row['url']).content)
```

Out:

```
SyntaxError: f-string: empty expression not allowed
```

***Reference link:***

[Loop url from dataframe and download pdf files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65176880/loop-url-from-dataframe-and-download-pdf-files-in-python)

Comment: Use pandas `df.iterrows()` or `df.itertuples()` and download to file with the name created already. You can prepare the filename like this `"{}-{}-{}-{}.pdf".format(r.city, r.type, r.year, r.quarter)` (assuming `r` is a row from `iterrows`).

Comment: Additional note: The `iterrows` returns a 2-tuple, the row object is the second item of the tuple.

Comment: I edit the code based on your suggestions, but it doesn't work out yet, please check the updated part.

Comment: The error is because you are using the `f-string` instead of normal string. Get rid of the `f` or use it like it is supposed to be.

Comment: Problem solved, many thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you please post a link to your entire source code? I am trying to figure out the same but I am not using pandas. Thanks